# Is it mandatory to have package names identical with artifactory's groupId of a project?

Tags: java, maven, package

I have a maven project whose pom looks like below:

```
<groupId>com.example.check</groupId>
  <artifactId>first-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

This project has `src/main/java` where all Java source code will reside.

Is it mandatory that package names should be identical to what is in pom's `artifactId` viz: `com/example/check`.

Can we give a different package name like: `abc/xyz/check`.

How is `package name` related to pom's `artifactId`. What is the connection between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, maven doesn’t  care.  It is just a binary blob which usually happen to have a special meaning to Java.

It will make the life of users (and maintainers) easier if you do at least *some* kind of alignment between the name and the contents of an artifact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell a bit about "some kind" of alignment?

Comment: If you own "curiousmind.org" it would be reasonable to expect that your Maven group id was "org.curiousmind.someproject" and that your Java classes are put somewhere under "org.curiousmind.someproject".    Nothing enforces you to - it is just what people expect.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory.

There are however conventions that people tend to follow. As per the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) on naming:

> A group ID should follow Java's package name rules. This means it starts with a reversed domain name you control. For example,
>   org.apache.maven, org.apache.commons
>
> Maven does not enforce this rule. There are many legacy projects that do not follow this convention and instead use single word group IDs. However, it will be difficult to get a new single word group ID approved for inclusion in the Maven Central repository

Java package names are arbitrary, as long as you follow satisfy the language syntax. See [official Oracle documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

In relation to `artifactId`, again this can be whatever you like.